# How to disable sticky keys

Tags: windows-xp

When I press shift five times, I get a "StickyKeys" dialog. It doesn't mather if I press OK, Cancel or Settings, the next time I press shift 5 times, the dialog comes up again.

Also, I don't have a `Accessibility Options` item in my Control Panel, nor do I have a `access.cpl` file on my C drive.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: The fact that you don't have access.cpl or an Accessibility Options in your copy of XP worries me more. Is this a legal copy? Are you in a domain environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it in the registry.

- Start -> Run -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Type **regedit** and press enter
- navigate to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER \Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys]`
- change the value of **Flags** to **10**
- navigate to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response]`
- change the value of **Flags** to **122**
- navigate to `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys]`
- change the value of **Flags** to **58**

or if you don't use any of the accessibility features, you can delete the whole Accessibility key (back it up first in case you need it in the future though).

Comment: Although this answer is correct (I upvoted) - I would still be curious about an answer to Nonapeptide's question. Not having the accessability functions seems odd to me as well.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me. However, I managed to get a copy of the access.cpl file (which wasn't installed on our enterprise installation), and just disabled every function checkbox I could find. This works; however I have no idea which registry key this is...

Comment: @John T: when you change [HKEY_CURRENT_USER \Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys] Flags from 506 to 10, I can accept this answer.

Comment: 10 worked? interesting, edited accordingly.

Comment: I did not forget. Jeff's UI doesn't let me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Press shift 5 times again to bring up the stickykeys dialog.  Click "settings".  Uncheck "Use Stickykeys" **AND** click "Settings".  Uncheck "Use Shortcut".

Comment: Click settings doesn't (in my case) open a dialog. That's the problem...

Comment: My mistake.  That wasn't clear from your description.  I've found that most of the time people neglect to disable the shortcut, only disabling stickykeys itself.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue that often come up is how to turn off FilterKeys. You can do that by To holding down both Shift Keys.